# Weak interaction of $(\nu^c)_R$ fields of the SM and $N_R$ fields in type-I seesaw extension of the SM

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, neutrinos, weak-interaction

The antiparticle of $\nu_L$ is given by its charge conjugated field i.e., $(\nu_L)^c$ which is equal to $(\nu^c)_R$. Both $\nu_L$ and $(\nu^c)_R$ are part of the Standard Model (SM) of massless neutrinos. See the answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/101114/neutrinos-and-anti-neutrinos-in-the-standard-model?rq=1) by JeffDror.

$\bullet$ *How can $(\nu^c)_R$ take part in weak interaction which always couple the left-chiral fields? I'm looking for the relevant piece of the Lagrangian.*

$\bullet$ *Why a Dirac mass cannot be written down using the left-handed $\nu_L$ field and the right-handed $(\nu^c)_R$ field?*

$\bullet$ *If $(\nu^c)_R$ fields can take part in weak interaction, does it mean $N_R$ fields (fields introduced in the type-I seesaw extension of the SM) can also take part in weak interaction?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are not asking for a tutorial of the Dirac & Majorana equations or *C*, amply covered in standard texts like Li & Cheng, Schwartz, or Ramond’s “Journeys Beyond the Standard Model” —the horse’s mouth! You might prefer [Klauber](http://www.quantumfieldtheory.info/TheSeesawMechanism.htm). I’ll just answer your narrower questions with the standard mnemonic.

First, go back to pre superKamiokande days, so, then without a weak singlet $\nu_R$ sterile neutrino, so neutrino Dirac masses —or a seesaw speculated upon in 1979.
So all neutrinos and antineutrinos have weak charge (doublet indices partnered with those of the charged leptons), conjugate to each other.

$\nu_L$ destroys a LH neutrino and creates a RH antineutrino.

Its hermitian conjugate, $\overline{\nu_L}$, creates a LH neutrino and destroys a RH antineutrino.

The SU(2)-symmetric charge current vertex (+h.c.) is then proportional to 
$$
W^-_\mu  \overline{e_L} \gamma^\mu \nu_L   +     W^+_\mu  \overline{\nu_L } \gamma^\mu    e_L   ,
$$
where $e_L$ destroys a LH electron, and creates a RH positron, as before, and $\overline{e_L}$ creates a LH electron and destroys a RH positron. 
Since $W_\mu^-$ destroys a $W^-$ and creates a $W^+$, the first term of this charge-conserving (and weak isospin conserving) interaction destroys a LH neutrino and creates a LH electron and a $W^+$, etc. The second term, likewise, destroys a RH antineutrino and creates a RH positron and a $W^-$, etc, for all line reversals of your choice.

- So, your sweeping judgment that the weak vertices “only couple to LH fields” is unwarranted when the chirality-reversing bars  sheltering antiparticles are considered.  Now, since $\nu_L^c=C \overline{\nu_L}$ *does what* $\overline{\nu_L} $ *does* ;   and   $ \overline{\nu_L} ^c= -\nu_L C^{-1}$ *does what* $\nu_L $ *does*; and, mutatis mutandis for the electrons, the above weak vertex presents, perversely, as 
  $$
  W^-_\mu  e_L ^c\gamma^\mu  \nu_L    +     W^+_\mu \nu_L  ^c\gamma^\mu     e_L ,
  $$
  where the evident transposes are understood, so that a *c* superscript does what an overbar does. Again, the first term destroys a LH neutrino and creates a LH electron and a $W^+$, or else creates a RH antineutrino and destroys a RH positron and a $W^-$; etc for all line reversals of your choice.
- Because $\overline{\nu_L}  (\nu_L)^c$ is simply the definition of a Majorana mass, not the Dirac mass term; it preserves Lorentz invariance, but fails to obey the Dirac equation, as all QFT texts detail. It violates lepton number, as it destroys a LH neutrino and a RH antineutrino, or else creates a RH neutrino and a RH antineutrino. It is a source or sink term for lepton umber 2. (A corresponding term for the electron would also violate lepton number by 2, but, crucially ***electric charge*** by 2, as well, and of course would fail to be an isosinglet.) Therefore, if you looked at the weak indices, suppressed, you’d see that this term cannot be a weak isosinglet, so it is forbidden. (Except in the unrenormalizable, dimension 5,  “Weinberg term”, where each neutrino’s index is saturated to a singlet by the neutral component of a Higgs each, whose v.e.v. sinks into the vacuum taking away one total unit of weak isospin. I gather this is what you have in mind for your next question.)
- Enter sterile EW singlets (indexless) $\nu_R$ and the seesaw. Now the superheavy *N* will be mostly   $\nu_R$ with a tiny contamination  $O(m_D/M)$ component of (indexed!) $\nu_L^{~c}$, which, ipso facto, as you are surmising, *does* couple to the *W*s. *Nevertheless*, this is a minuscule component of order 100GeV/$10^{15}$GeV ~ $10^{-13}$, so, negligible. The major handle on this mixing, instead is through lepton number violation involving the other, the *light* eigenvector of the seesaw mass matrix, not *N*; it will enter into the neutrinoless double β decay.

Comment: Can you kindly explain how does $\nu_L$ create a RH antineutrino? All I know is that a Dirac neutrino field $\nu$ will destroy $\nu$-particle and create a $\bar{\nu}$-particle. If you prefer, I can ask it as a separate question. @CosmasZachos

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely a broader, more basic  question on the interpretation of Weyl spinors, so a different question. Check your thinking imagining there are *no* RH neutrinos and LH antineutrinos, and thinking of how the kinetic term of the LH neutrino could possibly survive, and the line reversals involved.

Answer (score 0):

Charge conjugation $(\nu_L)^c$ of left-handed neutrino $\nu_L$ is nominally right-handed, ie.
$$
P_R (\nu_L)^c = (\nu_L)^c, 
P_L (\nu_L)^c = 0.
$$
However, $(\nu_L)^c$ still walks and quacks in a semi-left-handed way. It carries, mutatis mutandis, left-handed charges. For example, $(\nu_L)^c$ has non-zero hypercharge. On the other hand, the hypercharge of $(\nu_R)^c$ remains zero, even though $(\nu_R)^c$ is nominally left-handed.

Comment: I wouldn't call $(\nu_L)^c$ a "semi-left handed" field or merely "nominally right-handed" at all. The handedness of a field just refers to its chirality, and $(\nu_L)^c$ is right-chiral and hence right-handed, end of story.

Comment: Unless you're defining "left-handed" to mean "has nonzero hypercharge", which seems to me a rather strange and artificial definition.

Comment: Folks usually allege that "left-handed"  neutrinos participate in electroweak processes, while "right-handed"  neutrinos won't.  "semi-left-handed" or "semi-right-handed" is used in that sense.

Comment: People say that, and it's completely correct. A left-helicity neutrino particle participates in an electroweak process, while a right-helicity neutrino particle doesn't. This doesn't say much about the chirality of the _fields_ involved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in that the question mixes up particles and fields. For example, the question speaks of "the antiparticle of a field", which doesn't make sense. In essence:

- We observe that only left-helicity neutrinos and right-helicity antineutrinos seem to exist, where a neutrino/antineutrino is defined to have positive/negative lepton number, respectively
- In general, a left-chiral massless $X$ field annihilates left-helicity $X$ particles and creates right-helicity anti-$X$ particles. The same is true swapping the words "left" and "right".
- Hence the particles observed can be accounted for with a left-chiral neutrino *field* $\nu_L$, which annihilates left-helicity neutrinos and creates right-helicity antineutrinos.
- The charge conjugate field $\nu_L^c$ is a right-chiral antineutrino field, because it annihilates right-helicity antineutrinos and creates left-helicity neutrinos.
- Thus, the exact same set of particles can be described by either a left-chiral neutrino field, or a right-chiral antineutrino field. So there's really no paradox as described in the question.

A lot of confusion in particle physics comes from mixing up particles and fields. In particular, there are two *completely different* definitions of charge conjugation for particles and for fields. We have used the notion of field charge conjugation, which never yields new particles, but particle charge conjugation can. For a lot more discussion about these subtleties, see my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/178658/why-do-we-need-complex-representations-in-grand-unified-theories/403960#403960).